# Cisco router 1841 and VPN

Tags: cisco

I have Cisco 1841 router with SDM. Our ISP allocated us static IP. Now I would like to setup VPN so that staff can work remotely. We are going to use Terminal service for this. But how to setup VPN using Cisco router? I know you can allocate RAS/VPN server role to Windows server 2003 server and open port no: 1723 for PPTP VPN. But I don't know how to allocate this through 1841.

I really appreciate any suggestions or best practices about setting up VPN in the present scenario.

Answer (score 1):

On the CLI:

```
ip nat inside source static tcp "RAS server ip address" 1723 "outside ip address or interface" 1723
```

You'll also have to permit gre and tcp 1723 on the inbound ACL on your outsde interface.

Comment: ITGuy24, You rock... It's working for me.. Thank you very much buddy....

Comment: No problem, glad I could help